# Is it okay to use client credentials grant type for authentication of a WEB API going to be consumed by SailPoint(IAM)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, webapi, sailpoint

I have an old windows application written in VB.NET with SQL server backend. Currently the new user additions, deletion, adding entitlements etc. are managed by an old approval workflow system. After getting approvals, the user details and entitlements are inserted in to the SQL server database table manually.

I am trying to integrate this application with the [SailPoint's](https://www.sailpoint.com/) Identity and access management. So the new user addition, deletion update and adding entitlements etc will be done through Sailpoint. For this, I would require to create a WEB API which can be called by Sailpoint and expose the functionalities(add user/delete user/add entitlements). The only consumer to this API is SailPoint.

I am new to OAuth and below are the grant types that I came across. But not sure which one I should be using in this particular scenario.
1.Implicit Grant
2.Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant
3.Client Credentials Grant
4.Authorization Code Grant

I have done research on the different authentication methods that we can use to secure the web api. But still confused on which one to apply in this scenario as this new web api is going to be made available in internet.
I already tried developing a POC with the **OAuth 2.0** with **password** grant type referring [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-oauth-2-0-rest-web-api-authorization-using-database-first-approach/). But when I read articles in the internet I found that the password grant type is not that secure and is deprecated.

Could you please advise on which grant type(client credentials/authorization code/implicit) to use in this scenario. I believe authorization code is used when the user is directly trying to access the API. In this scenario, SailPoint will be calling the API in the backend programmatically when they insert a new user in their UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good approach to use client credentials in this case because the communication between IIQ and your Web API can be considered an API-to-API communication, I mean, IIQ is acting on behalf of itself in this communication.

See this article for more details - https://dzone.com/articles/four-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods (bold part by myself)

> OAuth 2.0 provides several popular flows suitable for different types
> of API clients:
>
> Authorization code — The most common flow, it is mostly used for
> server-side and mobile web applications. This flow is similar to how
> users sign up into a web application using their Facebook or Google
> account.
>
> Implicit — This flow requires the client to retrieve an
> access token directly. It is useful in cases when the user’s
> credentials cannot be stored in the client code because they can be
> easily accessed by the third party. It is suitable for web, desktop,
> and mobile applications that do not include any server component.
>
> Resource owner password — Requires logging in with a username and
> password. In that case, the credentials will be a part of the request.
> This flow is suitable only for trusted clients (for example, official
> applications released by the API provider).
>
> **Client Credentials** —
> **Intended for the server-to-server authentication, this flow describes
> an approach when the client application acts on its own behalf rather
> than on behalf of any individual user.** In most scenarios, this flow
> provides the means to allow users to specify their credentials in the
> client application, so it can access the resources under the client’s
> control.